# Fanuc Robot: Get ROS to read I/O pins

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More of a general question, but has anyone figured out how to get a readout of any of the digital pins I/O within ros, as some form of a publisher?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294923/fanuc-robot:-get-ros-to-read-i/o-pins/) by [nquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/35879/nquattro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q272675 for what is essentially a duplicate.

Summary: use a fieldbus for any serious work (modbus, ethernet/ip, profinet, etc).

For debugging / simple stuff (non-production), see whether [fanuc_ros_cgio](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio) and [fanuc_ros_cgio_py](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py) can help.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1